# 'import' showing outdated versions after updating to Python 3.10 on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, package, google-colaboratory

after updating from Python 3.7 to 3.10 on Google Colaboratory when using pip the newly installed packages arent showing when using 'import'. [There's a demo at Colab on this link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ej3ChQNk4km9e70fJ9z0MGok3FF4L541?usp=sharing)

I Updated the python version using this

```py
!wget https://github.com/korakot/kora/releases/download/v0.10/py310.sh
!bash ./py310.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py310" --user
!python --version
```

And installed numpy using

```
!pip3 install numpy==1.22.4 --upgrade
```

Thing is, the newly installed version of numpy is showing on **pip**, at the **python3.10/site-packages** folder

```
!pip show numpy
```

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.22.4
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: 
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: pandas, torchvision
```

But import is using the preinstalled version on **3.7/dist-packages**.

using

```
import numpy
numpy.__version__
```

outputs

```
'1.21.6'
```

and

```
numpy.__config__
```

outputs

```
<module 'numpy.__config__' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/__config__.py'>
```

Re-starting the runtime to clear the cached versions of the packages didn't help either.

There's a way to detect and prioritize the packages on the **Python3.10** folder?